# Show lisbox like the built-in address book, possible?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a lisbox, containing about 1400 names. Is it possible to show this listbox in the same way as the address-book, where you get the letter "a", which is clickable, and then it shows all the letters, and then to click on e.g "S", and then it jumps down to S in the listbox?

Is there a control that expands the listbox to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [LongListSelector](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api) from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com).

I can recommend combining it with my [LongListCollection](https://github.com/Windcape/Diverse/blob/master/LongListSample/LongListCollection.cs) type, for the data source.

You can find a full example at https://github.com/Windcape/Diverse/tree/master/LongListSample

Comment: Ok Claus, thank you very much! I will try this with you LongListCollection. Maybe I'll get it working :p Heia Danmark!

Comment: I got it working! :) But, I have a small issue. Instead of using Textblock in the ItemTemplate, I'm using HyperLinkButton. I get it working, but when I try to use the Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}", it breaks with an "unspecified error". Do you know why?

Comment: You can't use a `TextBox` style for a `Button`. Use a `<HyperLink>` inline element instead of the button.